# With kafka-consumer-perf-test I get 2m msg/sec but with C# client I get 564k msg/s. How can I squeeze max performance of kafka client?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In both cases (Kafka built in performance test tool and C# Client) we read from same topic with 1 partition and replication factor 1.
[C# code is benchmark code from confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/test/Confluent.Kafka.Benchmark/BenchmarkConsumer.cs)

Kafka performance test command:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic topic2p1 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --messages 10000000 --threads 1
```

complete result of `kafka-consumer-perf-test`

[image]